# Serverless auto swagger how to add authentication in node js [serverless-auto-swagger]

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, swagger, serverless

Here now i am working on serverless auto swagger,I want to known how to add authentication from congito to serverless auto swagger.Anyone able to help me for this issues

[In swagger ui the auth was empty so how to add authorize on auto swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiLd2.png)

Comment: any one helps this issues

Answer (score 0):

in serverless-auto-swagger there is a property called apiKeyHeader, when using that it will populate the header here. this is how it's going to look like

> autoswagger:
>
> > apiKeyHeaders: ['Authorization', 'anyOtherName']